# Firebird DDEX Provider Visual Studio 2013 SP3 - Connection dialog disappears immediately

Tags: ado.net, firebird, provider, ddex

I've installed the latest Firebird ADO.Net Provider (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient-4.5.1.0.msi) and the latest Firebird DDEX Provider (DDEXProvider-3.0.1.0.msi).

Both providers are registered in GAC.

```
FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bae6c78ccb0fcdb3, processorArchitecture=MSIL

FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

The Firebird ADO.Net Provider is also registered in the "DbProviderFactories" Node of the machine.config (for both x86 and x64).

```
<add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/>
```

I'm trying to create a new Database Connection using the DDEX Provider in VS2013 SP3, but it's not
working. When I change any values in the "Firebird Data Source" connection dialog, the dialog disappears.

I debugged VS2013 in background with a 2nd VS2013 Instance and got this Output messages, while the connection dialog disappears:

```
FbDataConnectionUIControl::LoadProperties()
Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) des Typs "System.NullReferenceException" ist in FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.dll aufgetreten.

System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.FbDataConnectionUIControl.LoadProperties()
FbDataConnectionUIControl::LoadProperties()

Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) des Typs "System.NullReferenceException" ist in FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.dll aufgetreten.

System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.FbDataConnectionUIControl.LoadProperties()

Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) des Typs "System.NullReferenceException" ist in FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.dll aufgetreten.
```

Any ideas how I can get the provider to run or where I can look for other prerequisites?

Comment: I'd suggest you file a bug report on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET

Comment: I've just created a [bug report on tracker.firebirdsql.org](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-571). The link should work soon.

Comment: They've deleted my bug report immediately from the bug-tracker, with the comment "This is not a forum". :o( Seems that there's no support from the persons they know what happens inside DDEX..

Comment: Weird, I'd classify this as a bug, if not in the library itself, then in the documentation...

Comment: I think it's a Setup Bug. Additionaly the UI should check the drivers and settings and should show a related message instead of killing the dialog window.

Comment: make sure the FB provider is registered in the machine.config

Comment: It is registered in the machine.config files (x86 and x64). See above <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/>

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and after a week of googling I think I have found a fix.

Download and install the following:

1. Visual Studio SDK
2. Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider
3. Firebird DDEX Provider

When installing the providers, make sure to click on the "Advanced" button. This is needed for installing the DDEX provider as it will give you a chance to choose which versions of Visual Studio it will get installed on. Installation on the GAC and registry should be taken care of by the DDEX installer.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I removed the FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll from the GAC, uninstalled and reinstalled DDEX and registered the firebird client in C:\Program Files (x86)\FirebirdClient\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll (which i downloaded as an msi installer from firebirdsql.org

Not sure if this will fix your problem but worth a try.